# Java reflection, get the name of a generic class parameter

Tags: java, class, generics, reflection, parameters

I would like to get the name of a generic parameter of a class.
For instance :

```
public class A<B> {
...
}
```

and **in** this class i would like to the name of the class B. Like :

```
A<Solution> var = new A<Solution>();
```

I would like to have a way to have the String "Solution" somewhere in a method of A

If you have any idea i am here :)

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to pass in the `Class` instance as a constructor parameter:

```
class A<B> {
  private final Class<B> clazz;

  A(Class<B> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
  }

  String getName() {
   return clazz.getSimpleName();
  }
}

A<Solution> var = new A<>(Solution.class);
```

Comment: You can also get it by subclassing `A`. See Guava's `TypeToken` or Jackson's `TypeReference` for examples.

Comment: @shmosel that would be an appropriate solution if `B` needs to be generic. Would you consider adding that as another answer?

Comment: You need to have an explicit type either way, e.g., `new A<Solution>() {}`. It's just a bit cleaner, especially if you need to capture multiple type parameters.

Comment: @shmosel Yes. But it's a different approach (it's the inheritance approach, whereas mine is the compositional approach), so you should add it as an alternative answer.

Comment: I don't have the patience to write it up now. Feel free to do so.